# Publishes many empty values

Tags: angular, mean-stack, mean

I am trying to generate a project, where I have a series of targets on the one hand and a series of articles on the other. So the idea is that I load those articles where those targets are and if they do not match they do not show anything, for that I have generated the following code in the HTML file of the component:

```
<div *ngFor="let articulo of spiderService.articulos">
    <div *ngIf="articulo.titulo.includes(target.nombre)">
        <p *ngIf="true">{{articulo.titulo}} - test</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is that I have more than 3,200 articles and I load the following code:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="card-stacked  col s12"></div>
```

This div is generated by me 15 times, which is the number of targets that I have in the database, and within this div I generate another 3,200 divs one per article, if the title of the article matches the name of the target it shows me perfect on the screen, but those that do not match generates that empty div, which gives me a lot of problems for the design and others.

any solution?

Comment: I have some questions about your HTML template. Firstly, is there a reason why there's an `ngIf` already set to `true`? Remove that. Secondly, could you please provide the full code? I don't see any `div` with those CSS classes in the first code snippet. (Unless you mean the parent div?)

Comment: try ng-container?

Comment: If you already know what is are the articles related to each target, I think you should merge/concat this data inside of your controller, so on that case the view should received just the needed data. or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could split spiderService.articulos in several arrays (targetName1Articles, targetName2Articles and so on). 
You will populate these arrays on ngInit.
Doing it you can add in the card-stacked a ngIf checking if this arrays has a length > 0 for example:

```
<div _ngcontent-c1="" class="card-stacked  col s12" *ngIf="target1Articles && target1Articles.length > 0"></div>
```

Hope it can help you